# combining two lists of dicts to one list of dicts by specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to achieve the following:

given

```
a = [{'val': 10, 'count': 1}]
b = [{'val': 10, 'count': 4}, {'val': 20, 'count': 2}]
```

I would like to get

```
output = [{'val': 10, 'count': 5}, {'val': 20, 'count': 2}]
```

That is, merging 2 lists of dicts according to val: if in 2 dict instances the val is the same, combine by summing the counts, otherwise keep 2 instances.

By the way, performance is an issue, so an elegant and fast solution is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm aware. I have a naive solution. Get a set of vals. for each val iterate over both of the lists and create a combined dict, then append it to the resulting list. It's pretty much straight forward,  but I'm wondering if there's a more pythonic way of achieving that.

Comment: Are you aware you're implementing a meta-dictionary with a dictionary and a list?  Wouldn't it be easier to store your data like this?  `a = {10:1}; b = {10:4, 20:2}`

Comment: The data is a given. I can manipulate it, however I'm dealing with a huge dataset, so this might take too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Brionius idea you can manipulate you data using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [List comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

We will take the data and create a dict that we can use easily with Counter, then we can add up the data and finally revert back to the format we want(your original format).

```
from collections import Counter

a = [{'val': 10, 'count': 1}]
b = [{'val': 10, 'count': 4}, {'val': 20, 'count': 2}]
c = Counter()

[c.update({d['val']:d['count']}) for d in a + b]
print [{'val': k, 'count': v} for k, v in c.iteritems()]
```

Output:

```
[{'count': 5, 'val': 10}, {'count': 2, 'val': 20}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing and able to change your data structure to something a little simpler, like this:

```
a = {10:1}
b = {10:4, 20:2}
```

Then you can easily use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
c.update(a)
c.update(b)

print dict(c)
# Result:
# {10: 5, 20: 2}
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately the data I'm getting is a given, and there are several TBs of it. Changing it will be a last resort.